# jsPDF , TypeError: pdf.fromHTML is not a function in REACT

Tags: reactjs, jspdf

i am using the next code to convert HTML to PDF using jsPDF and a simple react component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

const styles = {
    fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
    textAlign: 'center',
};
const colstyle = {
    width: '30%',
};
const tableStyle = {
    width: '100%',
};

const Prints = () => (
    <div>
        <h3>Time & Materials Statement of Work (SOW)</h3>
        <h4>General Information</h4>
        <table id='tab_customers' class='table table-striped' style={tableStyle}>
            <colgroup>
                <col span='1' style={colstyle} />
                <col span='1' style={colstyle} />
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr class='warning'>
                    <th>SOW Creation Date</th>
                    <th>SOW Start Date</th>
                    <th>Project</th>
                    <th>Last Updated</th>
                    <th>SOW End Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dec 13, 2017</td>
                    <td>Jan 1, 2018</td>
                    <td>NM Connect - NMETNMCM</td>
                    <td>Dec 13, 2017</td>
                    <td>Dec 31, 2018</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>
            This is a Time and Materials Statement of Work between Northwestern Mutual Life
            Insurance Company and Infosys with all general terms and conditions as described
            in the current Master Agreement and its related documents
        </p>
    </div>
);

const print = () => {
    const string = renderToString(<Prints />);
    const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');

    console.log(typeof pdf);
    pdf.fromHTML(string);
    pdf.save('pdf');
};

const Prescription = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>RECETA</h1>
            <div style={styles}>
                <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {'\u2728'}</h2>
                <button onClick={print}>print</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Prescription;
```

The error is:

> TypeError: pdf.fromHTML is not a function

How can I fix the error?

I tried to look for the "Typeof" and it shows "Object".

I want to convert the HTML in the REACT component to a downloadable PDF in the client side.

Answer (score 5):

Your implementation is perfectly right. This issue is happening because of `jspdf` version. Don't use the latest version instead use `V1.4.1` (see the attached screenshot).

Working Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-platform-7f26p?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Comment: Downgrading is not the answer, especially if the method is was just renamed. Answer by Maxamillion Scoof is the way to go

Answer (score 5):

Use `.html()` function

Documentation:
[http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#~html](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#%7Ehtml)

Edit: I realize my post was not enough explanation. You do not need to switch to a different version of jsPDF. The renamed the fromHtml() method to html() method. Everything you know about fromHtml() is exactly the same as html() (to my knowledge).

Comment: Your answer could be improved by including concise, relevant code rather and an explanation instead a link.

Comment: Best answer. Downgrading is generally not a good idea, as suggested in the other answers...

Comment: @Maxamillion Scoof. I tried .html() but now it's throwing error in console. Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not load dompurify: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk node_modules_dompurify_dist_purify_js failed.

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall the latest package with below mentioned command:

```
npm uninstall jspdf
```

Install older version by using below command

```
npm install jspdf@1.4.1
```

Comment: I tried it but another error occurred, the solution proposed by Maxamillion Scoof, seem correct